# SQLite - contar as chaves primárias que não foram referenciadas como chave estrangeira

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sqlite, select

- Primeiramente, estou tentando contar as chaves primárias de uma tabela que FORAM e que NÃO FORAM referenciadas como chave estrangeira em outra tabela.
- Além disso, quero filtrar a busca utilizando a clausula **LIKE** para mostrar somente as que contém determinada letra de um determinado atributo.

Vejam a explicação na imagem abaixo ([original aqui](https://scontent-b-iad.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn2/t1.0-9/10172678_1395295060746783_1728706954_n.jpg)):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou usando esta QUERY:

```
SELECT l.identifier AS id, l.name AS listName, COUNT(p.list_identifier) AS regCount 
FROM list AS l 
LEFT OUTER JOIN person AS p ON l.identifier = p.list_identifier
WHERE p.list_identifier IS NULL
GROUP BY l.name
```

Porém, ela faz a contagem das chaves estrangeiras que não foram referenciadas e sem a clausula LIKE. Por favor, se alguém puder me dar um exemplo de QUERY que faça esta busca, eu agradeço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente:

```
SELECT l.identifier AS id, l.name AS listName, 
 CASE COUNT(coalesce(p.list_identifier,0)) WHEN 0 THEN 'Não referenciado' ELSE 'Referenciado' END AS Situacao
 FROM list AS l LEFT OUTER JOIN person AS p ON l.identifier = p.list_identifier
  WHERE atributo LIKE '%l%'
   GROUP BY l.name
```

Desculpe, coloquei o coalesce na posição errada.

```
SELECT l.identifier AS id, l.name AS listName, 
 CASE coalesce(COUNT(p.list_identifier,0)) WHEN 0 THEN 'Não referenciado' ELSE 'Referenciado' END AS Situacao
 FROM list AS l LEFT OUTER JOIN person AS p ON l.identifier = p.list_identifier
  WHERE atributo LIKE '%l%'
   GROUP BY l.name
```

Comment: Vou tentar agora aqui @Osvaldo. Já te dou um feedback.

Comment: Mostrou todas como referenciado @Osvaldo , incluindo a que não foi referenciada. O que pode ser?

Comment: Arrumei aqui @Osvaldo . Nossa, muito obrigado. Fico grata com sua ajuda tão rápida. Me salvou ;) Beijos.